# מלא יד - full hand, meaning?

Tags: grammar-dikduk, commentaries, language, book-of-chronicles

I've a question about the combination of words מלא יד as shown in verses like Shemot 29:35, 32:29, Vayikra 8:33, Bamidbar 3:3, 1 Divrei HaYamim 29:5, 2 Divrei HaYamim 6:4, 6:15, 13:9, 29:31 etc...

Why the wording 'full of hand' as a idiom for dedication, consecration? 
In English this would seem like someone is busy or occupied.

So could someone explain me the connection between full hand and the consecration/dedication mentioned in the verses I quoted?